# JAVA - Process HttpClient request for Content-Type: application/json

Tags: java, php, spring, yii2

Hope everyone is doing great.

**problem**:
I am getting the following response every time I make a call to api for login via POST request

```
[status] => 415
[error] => Unsupported Media Type
[message] => Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Here is my code for **Yii2 application Side**:

```
$url = ['auth/login'];
$data = ['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password];

$response = \Yii::$app->apiclient->createRequest()
    ->setMethod('post')

    ->setUrl($url)

    ->addHeaders(['Accept-Charset' => 'UTF-8'])
    ->addHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json'])
    ->addHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])
    ->addHeaders(['Accept-Language' => \app\helpers\Helper::getUserLanguage()])

    ->setData($data)

    ->send();

return $response;
```

Here is what my apiclient setting is in web.conf file under components section

```
'apiclient' => [
            'class' => 'yii\httpclient\Client',
            'baseUrl' => 'http://myserverName:8000',
        ],
```

Here is my code for **Spring (JAVA) API side**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {}
```

**Target**:
I want to get user data from api on if login credentials (email & password) are correct. Or even a validation error message will do

**Context**: I am using Yii2 framework as my Application (front-end) and Spring (JAVA) as my back-end (API)

**side-note**:
the fun fact is that I am not even trying for content type `application/x-www-form-urlencode` as you can see in my Yii2 code but still I am getting the response mentioned in the problem.

Another fun fact is that when I call out for the same API in postman, I dont get any error and my response is exactly as it should be.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is this "apiclient" component in your PHP app? It looks like it's forcing the wrong content type header for the request.

Comment: apiclient is alias for yii\httpclient\Client. I have edited my question with its code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your request:

->setFormat(\yii\httpclient\Client::FORMAT_JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, BindingResult bindingResult) {}
```

This may help you..

***Thanks :)***

Comment: sorry, but I'll check this on monday now. I hope it works.

Comment: meanwhile can you explain this a bit please

Comment: check this link for explanation - https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-valid-requestbody

Answer (score 0):

The issue was wit the request I was sending to api.

Here is what I needed to do

```
$response = \Yii::$app->apiclient->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setUrl($url)
            ->setData($data)
            ->setFormat(\yii\httpclient\Client::FORMAT_JSON)

            ->addHeaders(['accept-charset' => 'utf-8'])
            ->addHeaders(['accept' => 'application/json'])
            ->addHeaders(['content-type' => 'application/json'])
            ->addHeaders(['accept-language' => \app\helpers\Helper::getUserLanguage()])

            ->send();
```

I added following line and it worked

```
->setFormat(\yii\httpclient\Client::FORMAT_JSON)
```

**Note**:

I have no idea about how and why it worked but this might be because PHP is a loosely typed language and JAVA is opposite. Java would ask for all minor details to be sent in order to process a request.